# Problems after installing Ubuntu 14.04 on previous Windows 7

Tags: disk-management

I had Windows 7 on my Sony Vaio E series laptop. Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it. Now when I start my system, the internal hard disk (seagate 500 GB) is making an intense sound of clicking, and the system stops sometimes as well.
My laptop is 4 years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say bad luck. It's very unlikely that a hard disc failure -- your issue sounds like you should buy a new one -- is caused by installation of Ubuntu. Do your backup and buy a new one. Also you might try to boot the live image of Ubuntu and maybe run smartctl for you disc.